# SQL ERROR [ mysqli ] Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list [1191]

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I faced this problem after importing the DB, recently i had to setup the fresh one so i used the already taken backup of files & db after importing db this following error shows,

General Error
SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]

Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list [1191]

SQL

```
SELECT  f.forum_id, f.forum_name, t.*,
        MATCH (t.topic_title) AGAINST ('some topic') AS score,
        fp.post_text AS first_post_text, lp.post_text AS last_post_text,
        fpu.user_avatar AS fp_avatar,
        fpu.user_avatar_type AS fp_avatar_type,
        fpu.user_avatar_width AS fp_avatar_width,
        fpu.user_avatar_height AS fp_avatar_height,
        lpu.user_avatar AS lp_avatar,
        lpu.user_avatar_type AS lp_avatar_type,
        lpu.user_avatar_width AS lp_avatar_width,
        lpu.user_avatar_height AS lp_avatar_height
    FROM  (phpbb_topics t)
    LEFT JOIN  phpbb_forums f  ON (f.forum_id = t.forum_id)
    LEFT JOIN  phpbb_posts fp  ON (fp.post_id = t.topic_first_post_id)
    LEFT JOIN  phpbb_users fpu  ON (fpu.user_id = t.topic_poster)
    LEFT JOIN  phpbb_posts lp  ON (lp.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id)
    LEFT JOIN  phpbb_users lpu  ON (lpu.user_id = t.topic_last_poster_id)
    WHERE  MATCH (t.topic_title) AGAINST ('some topic') >= 0.1
      AND  t.topic_status <> 2
      AND  t.topic_visibility = 1
      AND  t.topic_time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 315360000)
      AND  t.topic_id <> 8
      AND  f.similar_topics_ignore = 0
    LIMIT  5
```

BACKTRACE

FILE: (not given by php)
LINE: (not given by php)
CALL: msg_handler()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/driver.php
LINE: 994
CALL: trigger_error()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/mysqli.php
LINE: 193
CALL: phpbb\db\driver\driver->sql_error()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/mysql_base.php
LINE: 45
CALL: phpbb\db\driver\mysqli->sql_query()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/driver.php
LINE: 270
CALL: phpbb\db\driver\mysql_base->_sql_query_limit()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/factory.php
LINE: 321
CALL: phpbb\db\driver\driver->sql_query_limit()

FILE: [ROOT]/ext/vse/similartopics/core/similar_topics.php
LINE: 210
CALL: phpbb\db\driver\factory->sql_query_limit()

FILE: [ROOT]/ext/vse/similartopics/event/listener.php
LINE: 63
CALL: vse\similartopics\core\similar_topics->display_similar_topics()

FILE: [ROOT]/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php
LINE: 184
CALL: vse\similartopics\event\listener->display_similar_topics()

FILE: [ROOT]/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php
LINE: 46
CALL: Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/event/dispatcher.php
LINE: 62
CALL: Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/event/dispatcher.php
LINE: 46
CALL: phpbb\event\dispatcher->dispatch()

FILE: [ROOT]/viewtopic.php
LINE: 2370
CALL: phpbb\event\dispatcher->trigger_event()

Comment: i tried to import mysql db of phpbb and this issue occurs

Comment: what is `SHOW CREATE TABLE phpbb_topics`? Compare this to the original.

Comment: Is `t` missing `FULLTEXT(topic_title)`?